# Create Image Array to pass to imageDisplay activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, image

In my current app, I am able to create a listview that will display a picture in a second activity with a imagedisplay. However, because some entries have so many pictures, I am wanting to condense them into an array that will pass to the second activity, and the user will be able to swipe through the pictures. Below is my current code, and I am kind of stumped on how I may edit/change the code to include the array. Any recommendations?

```
public class adultcardiaclist extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;
    ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_adultcardiaclist);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9944401739416572~8067453677");

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adviews);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homebutton);

        //Home Button-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener () {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent protocolcata = new Intent(adultcardiaclist.this, HomeScreen.class);
                startActivity(protocolcata);
            }
        });

// myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("", R.drawable.ekghomepic));

        final Context context = getApplicationContext();

        //list contains image name, image location
        final List<ImageDisplay> myImageList = new ArrayList<ImageDisplay>();
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Asystole / PEA", R.drawable.adultasystole1));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Asystole / PEA Page 2", R.drawable.adultasystole2));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Bradycardia", R.drawable.adultbradycardia1));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Bradycardia Page 2", R.drawable.adultbradycardia2));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Cardiac Arrest", R.drawable.adultcardiacarrest1));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Cardiac Arrest Page 2", R.drawable.adultcardiacarrest2));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Cardiac Arrest Page 3", R.drawable.adultcardiacarrest3));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Chest Pain / STEMI", R.drawable.adultchestpain1));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Chest Pain / STEMI Page 2", R.drawable.adultchestpain2));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("CHF / Pulmonary Edema", R.drawable.adultchf1));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("CHF / Pulmonary Edema Page 2", R.drawable.adultchf2));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Tachycardia (Narrow Complex)", R.drawable.adulttachynarrow1));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Tachycardia (Narrow Complex) Page 2", R.drawable.adulttachynarrow2));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Tachycardia (Narrow Complex) Page 3", R.drawable.adulttachynarrow3));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Tachycardia (Wide Complex)", R.drawable.adulttachywide1));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Tachycardia (Wide Complex) Page 2", R.drawable.adulttachywide2));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Tachycardia (Wide Complex) Page 3", R.drawable.adulttachywide3));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("V-Fib / Pulseless V-Tach", R.drawable.adultvf1));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("V-Fib / Pulseless V-Tach Page 2", R.drawable.adultvf2));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Post Resuscitation", R.drawable.adultpostresus1));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Post Resuscitation Page 2", R.drawable.adultpostresus2));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Targeted Temperature Management", R.drawable.adulttargtemp1));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Targeted Temperature Management Page 2", R.drawable.adulttargtemp2));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("TEAM Focused CPR", R.drawable.adultteam1));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("TEAM Focused CPR Page 2", R.drawable.adultteam2));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Termination of CPR", R.drawable.adultterm1));
        myImageList.add(new ImageDisplay("Termination of CPR Page 2", R.drawable.adultterm2));



        //define ListView and create onItemClick Listener
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.adultcardiaclistview);

        ArrayAdapter<ImageDisplay> arrayAdapters = new ArrayAdapter<ImageDisplay>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, myImageList);
        listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapters);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, imagedisplay.class);

                myIntent.putExtra("name", myImageList.get(position).getName());
                myIntent.putExtra("imagePath", myImageList.get(position).getPath());
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });
    }


    public class ImageDisplay {
        private String Name;
        private int Path; // use String if you use a path, in here i'm storing image in drawable

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Name;
        }

        public ImageDisplay() {
        }

        public ImageDisplay(String name, int path) {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Path = path;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            Name = name;
        }

        public int getPath() {
            return Path;
        }

        public void setPath(int path) {
            this.Path = path;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your ImageDisplay class to implement Serializable. Now instead of adding individual items as extras to the intent, add a list of ImageDisplay objects.